# Mozilla FireFox :AJAX response of Success and Failure not working Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, firefox

I know this question is been asked many times but in a different context. so before ignoring the question please read the problem.

I am having a problem in **Mozilla Firefox** only.

I am using Laravel 5.2 and on frontend simple bootstrap 4 so when a form is submitted I make an ajax call, for example, a user dropping an email only, and on the success, it shows you the success signUp message
working perfectly in chrome and IE 10+ 
**Problem**
In Mozilla Firefox it shows the json "success"

**Ajax call**

```
 $('form#email-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            showSuccess();
        },
        error: function(resp) {
            showError();
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller **

```
public function storeEmail(Request $request)
{
    //Save Functionality
    return response()->json('success', 200);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what you expect from the server? as I'm able to see you have sent a success message from the server.

Comment: @NarayanSharma when i send status code 200 it means it should come back in ajax success method

Comment: Please click on the network tab from the debugger tool and attach the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function storeEmail(Request $request)

{
//Save Functionality
return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response but this is not working do i have to do something in ajax success response

Comment: it's not even coming back to the success call back function